# Is the second sentence correct? If not, how should I change it?

Tags: dates

> I would be available any time next Monday or Thursday. Please let me know if any of those dates work for you.

Comment: Which sentence are you concerned about, the first or second?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: You are not offering dates, but times in either of those dates. Please let me know which time slot works for you.

Comment: What makes you think it might not be correct? It's a perfectly normal sentence that has been said millions of times.

Comment: Keep it simple: "When would you like to meet?"

Comment: Also, I'd say "I will" rather than "I would".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence is both contextually and grammatically correct. It is a logical way to ask if the mentioned dates are suitable for the recipient. But as others mentioned in the comments to your question, there’re some simpler ways to ask the same question.